# Is there a way to get the logs from port forwarding using AWS System Manager Session Manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, portforwarding

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently working with AWS System Manager Session Manager and utilizing port forwarding for my setup. I'm facing an issue where I need to access the logs related to the port forwarding sessions for auditing purposes.

Is there a way to get the logs for the inputs/outputs? Has anyone encountered a similar situation or knows how to access these logs?

Thanks in advance!